# How to remove the RichEdit shortcuts?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, richedit

As described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787873%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#rich_edit_shortcut_keys), RichEdit controls have a lot of built-in shortcuts for various functions.

I have `TRichEdit` controls in a Delphi 7 application where I would like to remove some (but probably not all) of those shortcuts. There is no such method described in msdn.

I am currently simply using `OnKeyDown` and `OnKeyUp` event handlers for this purpose, but this isn't a very elegant solution, since I have to add code for every `TRichEdit` control, and often I'm adding `OnKeyDown` and `OnKeyUp` event handlers only for this.

I would like to implement a more elegant solution that deals with those shortcuts globally, like using an interceptor class, but I don't know how to intercept and discard those shortcuts. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could add your own shortcut handlers that do nothing. Add an action list and add an action. Use the action's `ShortCut` and `SecondaryShortCuts` properties to hijack the shortcuts you are targeting. Add on `OnExecute` handler for the action that does nothing, or perhaps beeps to indicate an un-handled short cut.

I don't know for sure that this will work having never tried it, but I believe it should.

Comment: It seems to be working, although I don't like the approach very much. What shortcut would you write to handle the CTRL+LeftSHIFT and CTRL+RightSHIFT shortcuts though?

Comment: I don't understand. Those are not shortcuts.

Comment: They are in the RichEdit control, see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787873%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#rich_edit_shortcut_keys). They change the alignment in RTL BiDi mode. Which is pretty awful if you ask me, for example CTRL+SHIFT can be used to change the input language.

Comment: OK, did not know that. I don't think my suggestion is going to help. I'm curious though. Why do you want to make this control less functional.

Comment: Well, the app the control's used in allows only style and color formatting. The user shouldn't be able to make superscript/subscript text, change the line height or the alignment. And CTRL+SHIFT is the most awful idea for a shortcut I could imagine: that's Window's default keyboard layout switching shortcut, and it can even be assigned to switch the input language. I'm not removing all of the shortcuts, only about a dozen of them or so. Also, some of the shortcuts are already assigned to menus in my app. Plus I don't like not having control (pun intended) over my controls.